# Testing a vbscript using HP UFT

Tags: testing, vbscript, hp-uft

I am automating a Test of a VbScript through HP UFT. I want to submit to the script several Variables and then capture the output of my Script.

So far i have started the script with a click from the user-interface. However this does not allow me to get information back from the test case.

I think i have several options:

- starting it with cmd
- starting it using parameters

**EDIT:**

I have now integrated this script into UFT itself. However the script starts another Application. From the vbscript this runs fine. However from within UFT i get a "General run error". 
My code is as follows:

```
Set App = CreateObject( "CANoe.Application")
Set Measurement = App.Measurement
WScript.ConnectObject App, "App_"
```

Albeit the `Createobject` fails already. From within VBscript everything is OK.

But I have no clue as to how I get the output of my script back into my test case.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: What type of output are you expecting? An integer? A string? A body of text?

Comment: Post your code, how you are trying?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the COM Model of the Application i am starting. Failing that i am expecting simple Text.

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the variable name to a word OTHER THAN 'App', I ran into this issue previously and mine worked when I changed the variable name.

For example:

Set newApp = CreateObject( "CANoe.Application")